# Saving data in datagridview so that it persists after closing program

Tags: database, vb.net, datagridview, save

I know there's a lot on this topic, but I couldn't seem to take the information and customize it to my code. **I'm having a problem saving my data so that the data persists when I close the program and open it again.** It's a simple program where data gets entered through text boxes into the data grid view. At first nothing was happening, but after hours of working on my code I'm starting to get this error message on the `dataAdapter.Update(dt)` line:

> Dynamic SQL generation is not supported against multiple base tables.

I know my code isn't following the best practice rules, but I'm very new to programming so play nice. Thanks in advance, I really do appreciate the help.

Here's my code:

```
Public Class frmGradeBook
    'data grid view for recording students grades
    Dim connStr As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source=GRADEBOOK.accdb"
    Dim sqlStr As String = "SELECT firstName,lastName,firstExam,secondExam,finalExam " & _
                    "FROM Students INNER JOIN Grades ON Students.studentID = Grades.studentID "
    Dim dataAdapter As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sqlStr, connStr)
    Dim dt As New DataTable()

    'secondary data grid view for displaying students grade
    Dim connStr1 As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source=GRADEBOOK.accdb"
    Dim sqlStr1 As String = "SELECT firstName, lastName, finalExam FROM Students INNER JOIN Grades ON Students.studentID = Grades.studentID "
    Dim dataAdapter1 As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sqlStr1, connStr1)
    Dim dt1 As New DataTable()

Private Sub frmGradeBook_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    dataAdapter.Fill(dt)
    dgvRecordGrades.DataSource = dt

    dataAdapter1.Fill(dt1)
    dgvDisplayGrades.DataSource = dt1

    dgvDisplayGrades.Visible = False
    lstGrade.Visible = False

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRecord.Click

    dgvDisplayGrades.Visible = False
    dgvRecordGrades.Visible = True
    lstGrade.Visible = False

    'validates the data
    Dim studentID As String = txtID.Text.ToUpper
    Dim row As Integer
    Dim dataGridRow As DataGridViewRow = dgvRecordGrades.Rows(1)

        If IsNumeric(txtFirstExam.Text) And IsNumeric(txtSecExam.Text) And IsNumeric(txtFinalExam.Text) Then
            If (txtFirstExam.Text).ToString().IndexOf(".") = -1 Then
                Dim firstExam As Double = CDbl(txtFirstExam.Text)
                Dim secondExam As Double = CDbl(txtSecExam.Text)
                Dim finalExam As Double = CDbl(txtFinalExam.Text)

                If firstExam <= 100 And secondExam <= 100 And finalExam <= 100 Then
                    If firstExam >= 0 And secondExam >= 0 And finalExam >= 0 Then

                        If studentID = "AJ-123456" Then
                            row = 0
                        ElseIf studentID = "FA-192837" Then
                            row = 1
                        ElseIf studentID = "GG-567876" Then
                            row = 2
                        ElseIf studentID = "GJ-987654" Then
                            row = 3
                        ElseIf studentID = "LS-222333" Then
                            row = 4
                        Else
                            MessageBox.Show("The student ID provided is not valid. Please try again.")
                        End If

                    'records the grades
                        dgvRecordGrades.Item(2, row).Value = firstExam
                        dgvRecordGrades.Item(3, row).Value = secondExam
                        dgvRecordGrades.Item(4, row).Value = finalExam

                    Else
                        MessageBox.Show("Invalid input. Please try again")
                    End If
                Else
                    MessageBox.Show("Invalid input. Please try again")
                End If
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter whole numbers. Try again.")
            End If

        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid input. Please try again")
        End If


End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click_2(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPostable.Click
    dgvRecordGrades.Visible = False
    dgvDisplayGrades.Visible = False
    lstGrade.Visible = True

    lstGrade.Items.Clear()

    If Not IsDBNull((dgvDisplayGrades.Item(2, 0).Value)) Then
        lstGrade.Items.Add("3456    " & LetterGrade(CDbl(dgvDisplayGrades.Item(2, 0).Value)))
    Else
        lstGrade.Items.Add("3456    NO GRADE AVAILABLE")
    End If

    If Not IsDBNull((dgvDisplayGrades.Item(2, 1).Value)) Then
        lstGrade.Items.Add("2837    " & LetterGrade(CDbl(dgvDisplayGrades.Item(2, 1).Value)))
    Else
        lstGrade.Items.Add("2837    NO GRADE AVAILABLE")
    End If

    If Not IsDBNull((dgvDisplayGrades.Item(2, 2).Value)) Then
        lstGrade.Items.Add("7876    " & LetterGrade(CDbl(dgvDisplayGrades.Item(2, 2).Value)))
    Else
        lstGrade.Items.Add("7876    NO GRADE AVAILABLE")
    End If

    If Not IsDBNull((dgvDisplayGrades.Item(2, 3).Value)) Then
        lstGrade.Items.Add("7654    " & LetterGrade(CDbl(dgvDisplayGrades.Item(2, 3).Value)))
    Else
        lstGrade.Items.Add("7654    NO GRADE AVAILABLE")
    End If

    If Not IsDBNull((dgvDisplayGrades.Item(2, 4).Value)) Then
        lstGrade.Items.Add("2333    " & LetterGrade(CDbl(dgvDisplayGrades.Item(2, 4).Value)))
    Else
        lstGrade.Items.Add("2333    NO GRADE AVAILABLE")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDisplay.Click
    dgvDisplayGrades.Visible = True
    dgvRecordGrades.Visible = False
    lstGrade.Visible = False

    For col As Integer = 2 To 2
        For row As Integer = 0 To 4
            If Not IsDBNull(dgvRecordGrades.Item(col, row).Value) Then
                Dim firstExam As Double = CDbl(dgvRecordGrades.Item(2, row).Value)
                Dim secExam As Double = CDbl(dgvRecordGrades.Item(3, row).Value)
                Dim finalExam As Double = CDbl(dgvRecordGrades.Item(4, row).Value)
                dgvDisplayGrades.Item(2, row).Value = SemAvg(firstExam, secExam, finalExam)
            Else
            End If
        Next
    Next

End Sub


Function SemAvg(firstMid As Double, secondMid As Double, final As Double) As Double
    Dim semAverage As Double
    semAverage = (firstMid + secondMid + (2 * final)) / 4
    Math.Round(semAverage)
    Return semAverage
End Function


Function LetterGrade(semAvg As Double) As String
    Select Case semAvg
        Case Is >= 90
            Return "A"
        Case Is >= 80
            Return "B"
        Case Is >= 70
            Return "C"
        Case Is >= 60
            Return "D"
        Case Else
            Return "F"
    End Select
End Function



Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    Dim changes As Integer
    Dim commandBuilder As New  _
                            OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(dataAdapter)
    changes = dataAdapter.Update(dt)
    If changes > 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show(changes & " changed rows.")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("No changes made.")
    End If

End Sub


Private Sub frmGradeBook_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
    dataAdapter.Dispose()
    dataAdapter1.Dispose()

End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

I think following is the problem.

You are filling up the *datatable dt* from dataAdapter which contains following

> *commandText=*

```
"SELECT firstName,lastName,firstExam,secondExam,finalExam " & _
            "FROM Students INNER JOIN Grades ON Students.studentID = Grades.studentID "
```

which is retrieving data from *two* table.

And to get *automatic* update command  from *dataAdapter*, you have to retrieve data from *only one* table having a *primary key*.

> You can't retrieve from more than one table to use *dataAdapter.UpdateCommand* property.

Hope this helps.